# Secure Access to Office365

Tags: sharepoint-online

In our environment untrusted laptops are used. Users share laptops amoung family members and don't login to the OS.
How can we define secure access to Office365 (sharepoint-online and outlook online) in this environment? So the cloud service must enforce secure identification I think and caching credentials at the laptop alone should not give access.
Please help.
Jan

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this, and I'm sure that there are others, is to enable MFA on all accounts.  This way even if someone does save creds in their browser, they still get prompted for the MFA.

Comment: Two questions: 1- what happens when the user does not log off or how long does the session live? 2-microsoft encourage the user to use local Word/Excel etc when the users opens a document from sharepoint online, is MFA effective here too? Once the user has used local Word the service with credentials are locally cached and the next user of the untrusted device has access to sharepoint online.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Josh said, the easiest solution will be using MFA which requires the users to do two-step verification for access.

For how to set up MFA, please check this: [Set up multi-factor authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/security-and-compliance/set-up-multi-factor-authentication?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fenable-8f0454b2-f51a-4d9c-bcde-2c48e41621c6&view=o365-worldwide)

After that, ask the users to [set up 2-step verification for Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-up-2-step-verification-for-office-365-ace1d096-61e5-449b-a875-58eb3d74de14)

We strongly recommend setting up more than one verification method. For example, if you travel a lot, consider [setting up Microsoft Authenticator](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-microsoft-authenticator-with-office-365-1412611f-ad8d-43ab-807c-7965e5155411) for your verification method. It's the easiest verification method to use, and a way to avoid text or call charges.

Comment: Jerry would you please comment what user3748911 said about his tests. Is it possibly an issue with the configuration? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think MFA is not a watertight solution to the question. I have tested this in these steps:

1. logged in to office.com (using MFA). Do not remember password, do not stay logged in.
2. opened a Word document in the local APP
3. logged out of office.com and closed the browser
4. Closed the document and closed Word
5. Opened Word again (local APP), and the document could be opened from the Recent-list without being asked for a password or MFA verification.

I think Jan (and I) is looking for a solution to prevent documents from being accessed localy when not being authenticated.